# How can I rename a bit addressable RAM of 8051 in IDA Pro?

Tags: assembly, ida, 8051

I need to rename a bit-addressable location of RAM in 8051 microcontroller.
I used IDA PRO to disassemble a binary file, and the output looks like this:

```
clr    RAM_29.3    
clr    RAM_29.7     
clr    P1.5
```

I can rename Port P1 or memory RAM_29, but how can I rename each bit of those variables? Is it possible in IDA PRO disassembler to do something like:

```
(clr TXpin)
```

instead of

```
(clr P1.5)     -------   ( P1.5 == TXpin )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Metalink's ASM51, I do this:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;                                       ;
;       Port pin assignments            ;
;                                       ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
                                        ;
LCD_RS          equ     acc.5           ; We operate on LCD bits in
LCD_E           equ     acc.6           ;  the accumulator because
LCD_RW          equ     acc.7           ;   P4 is not bit-addressable
LCD_BF          equ     acc.7           ;
                                        ;
RELAY           equ     P0              ; Relays are on P0.0-P0.3
                                        ;
DRDY            equ     P0.7            ; SPI pacing from keypad IC
                                        ;
PIEZO_PIN       equ     P1.7            ; Beeper output pin
```

For any port (or address) that is bit-addressable, `Px.y` or `Addrx.y` will resolve to a number, and so you can use EQU on it.  The same with `Px`, so you can see that I named P0 `RELAY` -- later on I can use `RELAY.0`, `RELAY.1`, and so on.

You can assign multiple names to the same bit; see `ACC.7` above.

Comment: Metalink's ASM51 isn't IDA Pro.